# How to group by counted value (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have this Dataframe:

| SerialNr | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |

And I want a table that shows me how many serial numbers in the right column have the same numbers.
Here for example it would look like this

| Amount | Quantity of SerialNr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

It should sum up the Serialnummer with the same amount

Tried to do it with groupby but did not work

Comment: `df['Quantity of SerialNr'] = df.groupby('Amoun').transform('size')`, but your example seems incorrect

Answer (score 1):

From your expected ouput need `Quantity of Amount`, so use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by `range` starting by `1`:

```
s = df['Amount'].value_counts()

df = (s.reindex(range(1, s.index.max()+1), fill_value=0)
       .rename_axis('Amount')
       .reset_index(name='Quantity of Amount'))
print (df)
   Amount  Quantity of SerialNr
0       1                     0
1       2                     2
2       3                     1
3       4                     1
```

Or use [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
cats = range(1, df.Amount.max()+1)
df = (pd.Categorical(df['Amount'], categories=cats)
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('Amount')
        .reset_index(name='Quantity of Amount'))

print (df)
  Amount  Quantity of Amount
0      1                   0
1      2                   2
2      3                   1
3      4                   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([df.set_index('SerialNr'), 
            df['Amount'].value_counts().rename('Quantity of Amount')], axis=1)
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer').reset_index()
 .drop('Amount', axis=1).rename({'index': 'Amount'}, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   Amount  count
0       1      0
1       2      2
2       3      1
3       4      1
```